# Homepage redirects to /wordpress

Tags: wordpress

The website URL is : [nawhrd.org](http://http:%20//nawhrd.org). 
ut it automatically redirects to nawhrd.org/wordpress.

The other pages are fine, but only the homepage is redirecting to /wordpress. How to not make it redirect to /wordpress?

Here is what I have tried:

1. Paste all folders out of /wordpress to public_html
2. Change siteurl and home url from database `wp-option`.
3. The permalink also seems to not have /wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just visited it here in an anonymous tab and it works (without the /wordpress). Maybe a local cache issue? Have you tried opening it in an anonymous tab as well or cleaning your browser cache?